# making a calendar object a string

Tags: android, string, calendar, simpledateformat

I'm a newbie to this so be gentle!

I'm trying to parse a calendar object which I have incremented by 1 month to a string so that I can add it to a String Builder and eventually print it using a Bluetooth Printer.

Here's the code I'm currently trying to use;

```
else if 

(Res.equals("&EXCLEND")){
                       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 

                       cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

                       SimpleDateFormat excluEnd = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-YYYY-hh-mm");

                       String EndDateString ="";
                     // cal.DAY_OF_MONTH.toString() + "/" + cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, cal.SHORT, cal.Locale.UK);

                     //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  EndDateString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                         try {
                              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(EndDateString));
                              while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
                                 output +=(char)c;
                                 newword +=(char)c;
                                 if(newword.equals(" ")|| newword.equals(".")){
                                    if(OutputColumn+output.length() <= 29){
                                        ret5.append(output);
                                        OutputColumn =OutputColumn+output.length();
                                        output = "";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        ret5.append("\r");
                                        ret5.append(output);
                                        OutputColumn = output.length();
                                        output = "";
                                    linecount ++;
                                    }
                                 }
                                 newword = "";
                              }

                         }
                        catch (IOException e) {}
                       }
```

In principal, I know that the code for the print string works as I have a piece of code to print the current date working fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I didn't understand the question. Care to elaborate?

Comment: The problem being that it errors on the print when it gets to the String EndDateString line and misses the entire of the print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is print a calendar object as a string than something like this should work

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.getTime().toString();
```

Comment: could i put this at the end of the code to make it

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
cal.getTime().toString();??

Comment: New question, How can you then format that output to "20 January 2012" for example.

Comment: you might run into an issue using the `.toString` right after adding a value to the calendar because I am not 100% sure if the calendar class will recalulate the Calendar attributes right after. You might need to call some other function before calling the Calendar's `toString()` function